# How to create Bootstrap 4 Cards dynamically using PHP while-loop with proper Layout

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

For my project I want to make a plant_booking online shop, in which I add plants from the admin panel, then show them on the index.php page. But the problem I have isn't about functionality, it is about the layout of the Bootstrap 4 cards. For the main design and front-end, I am using Bootstrap 4. For my back-end code, I use PHP. The site is fully functional. I add plants in the code through PHP Dynamically. So the problem comes from the design part, in that case, the product (card) part.

Let me explain.

When i add plant without a while loop(in index.php) it shows 1 card as expected.

but when I used while loop it shows 3 cards in a vertical format, not in horizontal format.

For my project, I want to make an online shop, in which I add products, edit them or delete them. But the problem I have isn't about functionality, it is about the layout of the Bootstrap 4 cards. For the main design and front-end, I am using Bootstrap 4. For my back-end code, I use PHP. The site is fully functional. I add products in the code through PHP Dynamically. So the problem comes from the design part, in that case, the product (card) part.

Let me explain.

The products that I add are shown in bootstrap 4 cards. When I add a product, It's showing like this. This is looking all good, for now.

When I add more products, the layout changes like this, which is incorrect.

I want my 3 plants (cards) to align right in the same row. The cards should also be the same, as the card in the first picture. The next product (card 4) should go in the next row and etc.

I want my 3 cards in that format, link is here-
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/album/

This is the code from index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- navbar start here -->
    <div class="card shadow">
        <div class="card-body">


            <h2>

                <a href=".php">
                    <button class=" mr-3 btn btn-outline-warning">Admin Login</button>
                </a>

                <a href=".php">
                    <button class=" mr-3 btn btn-outline-primary">User Signup</button>
                </a>

                <a href=".php">
                    <button class="mr-3 btn btn-outline-dark">User Login</button>
                </a>

            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- navbar end here -->

    <!-- heading start here -->
    <div class="card shadow bg-success">
        <div class="card-body">

            <center>
                <b>
                    <h1 class="card-title text-dark mt-4 mb-4">plant booking</h1>

                </b>

                <h3 class="card-title text-white mt-4 mb-4">Save Plant, Save Earth...</h3>

            </center>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- heading end here -->

    <br>

    <!-- cart starts here -->
 


    <?php
    include("connection.php");

    $sql = "SELECT name FROM addplant";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);



    ?>

    <?php
         
            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>

            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="card border-secondary shadow my-2 " style="width: 17rem; height: 25rem">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <center>
                                <img style="width:230px; height:180px" class="card-img-top" src="img/2.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">
                            </center>

                            <br>
                            <p class="card-text text-left"><b>Name : </b><br><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></p>
                            <p class="card-text text-left"><b>Scientific Name : </b><br>Juglans</p>

                            <center>
                                <a href="booking.php" class="btn btn-secondary">Book</a>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
      <?php  }
        
    ?>


    <!-- cart ends here -->

    <!-- footer background image -->
    <img style="width: 1350px;" src="img/apple.jpg">
    <!-- footer background image -->


</body>

</html>

<style>
    button {
        float: right;
    }

    span {
        float: right;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, put that `<div class="container"><div class="row">..` outisde while loop . Because , currently on each iteration you are creating new rows.

Comment: Where Can I put <div class="container"><div class="row">, because when I put it above the while loop then only one card moves not three.

Comment: Put that before while loop i.e :  `<div class="container"><div class="row"><?php  while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?> //your <div class="col-sm-3"><?php } ?> </div></div>`